# How to accessing data in cv::mat when the image type is not known at deisgn time?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a set of input images and one output image and I need to combine the input images and create output image.

I have this code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < Height; ++j)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Width; ++i)
    {
        int xx,yy,Id;
        algo.calXY(i, j, xx, yy,Id);
        cv::Vec3b value=cubeImage.images[Id].at<cv::Vec3b>(yy,xx);
         output.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)=value;
    }
 }
```

This code works only if the input images are RGB without alpha channel.

How can I change it to so if input images are ARGB, it works properly?

I tried to replace `cv::Vec3b` with `cv::Vec<uchar, output.channels>,` but it is not compiling as it needs a compile time variable for type.

Comment: `switch(mat.channels){ case 1 : ...; case 3 : ... case 4: ...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this work by copying one channel at a time:

```
for (int j = 0; j < Height; ++j)
{
    uchar* orow = output.ptr<uchar>(j);

    for (int i = 0; i < Width; ++i)
    {
        int xx, yy, Id;
        algo.calXY(i, j, xx, yy, Id);  

        //cv::Vec3b value=cubeImage.images[Id].at<cv::Vec3b>(yy,xx);   
        uchar* mrow = cubeImage.images[Id].ptr<uchar>(yy);

        mrow += xx * output.channels(); 

        // output.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)=value;
        for(int c = 0; c < output.channels(); ++ c)
            *orow++ = *mrow++;
    }
}
```